# How to keep multiple copies of a file in single Git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I have a configuration file in two locations in my repo, used for two slightly different purposes in my application. The two copies of the file are always going to be slightly different. But, when I want to make changes to one, I often want most of those changes to be applied to the other as well.

Ideally I'd like something that behaves as if these two files are branches of each other, in their own repo, but I don't want to create a submodule just for this one config file.

Is there anything built into Git to support this scenario? Or do I just need to use a merge tool and do it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it'd be better to change your app so it can cope with two config files.  Then put the common stuff in one file that both instances use and the differences in app-instance-specific files.

Or do it by hand ;-)